# SqlDataReader: SqlException - Invalid object name (table)

Tags: c#, service

This service gets data from the API, checks for duplicates and saves it to the DB. Error occurs when SqlDataReader trying to retrieve data from table. When this code was in the ASP.NET project, everything was working fine.

```
List<Thumbnail> Thumbnails = new List<Thumbnail>();

var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/articles?_limit=100")
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Thumbnails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Thumbnail>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}

if (Thumbnails != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Thumbnails.Count; i++)
    {
        Thumbnails[i].PublishedAt = Thumbnails[i].PublishedAt.ToUniversalTime();
    }

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mobilesdb.dbo.thumbnails ORDER BY PublishedAt", conn)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.Text
    };
    SqlDataReader reader = await cmdr.ExecuteReaderAsync();//error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'mobilesdb.dbo.thumbnails'.'

    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail()
            {
                Title = reader.GetString(1),
                Url = reader.GetString(2),
                ImageUrl = reader.GetString(3),
                NewsSite = reader.GetString(4),
                Summary = reader.GetString(5),
                PublishedAt = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal(nameof(thumbnail.PublishedAt))),
                UpdatedAt = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal(nameof(thumbnail.UpdatedAt))),
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < Thumbnails.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Thumbnails[i].Title.Equals(thumbnail.Title) &&
                    Thumbnails[i].NewsSite.Equals(thumbnail.NewsSite) &&
                    Thumbnails[i].Summary.Equals(thumbnail.Summary))
                {
                    Thumbnails.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }

    reader.Close();
```

This is part of code that responsible for receiving data from API and checking for duplicates. Error occurs after initializing SqlDataReader object. The same code for retrieving data from database is in ASP.NET project and works perfectly, so problem isn't in sql request.
P.S.
Additional info from console (debug): `Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in mscorlib.dll An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Invalid object name 'thumbnails'.`

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the beginning, see which line is giving error, then check the database if that column really exists in the table in the database.

Comment: Error is do to "SELECT * FROM mobilesdb.dbo.thumbnails"Try square brackets SELECT * FROM [mobilesdb].[dbo.thumbnails]

Comment: What is your connectionstring value?

Comment: @Steve `private static readonly string connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;";`

Comment: @Pankaj I marked the line where the error occurs with a comment

Comment: I would try to remove the _mobilesdb.dbo._ from the select statement

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately, no result. I tried different ways.

Comment: also the _Initial Catalog=master_ in the connection string should be removed

Comment: In other words you are dealing with a _LocalDB_ instance of Sql Server. I don't know if the most sophisticated options for the connectionstring are available (or behave in the same way) for LocalDB that should be used only for testing or single user scenarios. So start with the most simple connectionstring and then add options when you are ready to test their functionality

Comment: I would use SQL Server Management Studio to debug SQL Statements.  The error messages in SSMS are much better than c# for sql queries. Once you get the queries correct you can then use the query in c# and they will work.

Comment: Your error is probably due to not have read access to the database.  You do have permission to connect to the server because the open is working.  Since it is working in ASP.NET is must be a credential issue.  So I'm assuming you must be using Windows Credentials (Trusted).  In VS you do not have AS ADMIN unless you start VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  You can verify what is cause exception by using SSMS.  The logs are under Management.  It will give full description of what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved my question. Since the problem concerned the connection to the database, I decided to deal with the connection string first. In my case it's - `private static readonly string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=mobilesdb; Initial Catalog=mobilesdb; Trusted_Connection=True;";`
After that, I changed the **Log on** parameter from the **Local System account** to my own in the service properties and everything started working correctly. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.